# mod_rewrite - stop repeating for each directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have spent hours trying to get a simple rewrite working, there must be an error in my fundamental understanding of mod_rewrite:

I want a rule that does the following substitution:

```
www.example.com/fr/ -> www.example.com/?lang=fr
```

which I have working, but for subdirectories:

```
www.example.com/fr/other/directories/ -> www.example.com/other/directories/?lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr
```

It seems the rule is being applied once for every sub-directory (it should only be applied once).
Also, a request without a trailing slash causes another `lang=fr` to be appended to the query string

The rule is located in the < VirtualHost > and not within a < Directory > tag

> RewriteRule ^/(en|fr|zh|gr|it)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [QSA]

I am also using the `DocumentIndex /index.php index.php` directive

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could try adding a `/` in your second rewrite just after `$s2` to experiment with the extra addition.
And try adding `[L]` to the conditions, might stop it repeating over every directory.

```
RewriteRule ^/(en|fr|zh|gr|it)/(.*)$ /$2/?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However, I've heard `[L]` behaves differently when in htaccess opposed to being in the httpd.conf - I'm no expert on it I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

To be certain a RewriteRule will only be applied once add this condition before:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^/(en|fr|zh|gr|it)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Because any internal redirection made by mod-rewrite (and you'll have a lot, even with the `[L]` tag) will have the `REDIRECT_STATUS` envirronement variable altered.

The `[L]` tag means stop the chain of rewriteRule in case you have some other rules there. But the result of the mod-rewrite rewrite in your directory will always be tested against his new destination (and here the new destination is the same directory), and rules will be applied for the rewritten content as if it was a new one (except this env variable is set).